# ¿Como puedo obtener el número mayor y menor?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para la universidad donde el usuario digita cierta cantidad de números a escoger y tengo que poder obtener el número mayor y menor.
Lo estoy haciendo en java, netbeans, el usuario digita los números en un TextField.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vale, no tengo exactamente lo que necesitas pero si digamos que un 98% jeje. Mira, lo acabo de hacer y te explico lo que debes añadir. Este es el código para pedir por consola:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MayorMenor {

public static void main(String[] args){        
    
    //Declaramos las variables de número mayor, menor y donde se almacenará
    //el número que digitemos.
    
    //Adicional declaramos nuestro Scanner para capturar desde el teclado.
    int menor;
    int mayor;
    int num;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Pedimos el número y ese lo ponemos como mayor y como menor para posterior
    //poder realizar la comparación de si el número que ingresamos es mayor o
    //menor que los que hemos digitado
    System.out.println("Digite número: ");
    num = sc.nextInt();
    menor = num;
    mayor = num;
    
    //Ahora entramos en un for, la condición deberá ser la cantidad de números
    //total - 1 ya que ya ingresamos un número, si deseas ingresar 20 números
    //entonces la condición irá hasta 19 siempre y cuando la hagas como la tengo
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        //Pedimos el número y lo capturamos en num
        System.out.println("Digite número: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        
        //Comparamos si num es mayor que el número mayor hasta el momento 
        //y de ser así, entonces ese será el nuevo número mayor
        if(num > mayor){
            mayor = num;
        }
        //Por el contrario si es menor que el número menor, será el nuevo menor
        if(num < menor){
            menor = num;
        }            
    }
    
    //Luego simplemente imprimimos el mayor y el menor
    System.out.println("El mayor es: " + mayor + " y el menor es: " + menor);
}    
}
```

Listo, ya teniendo eso como base, ahora lo que debes hacer es capturar lo que tienes en el TextField haciendo una conversión de String a int, eso se hace con un parseo, suponiendo que tu TextField se llama txtNumero, entonces en la variable num pondrías simplemente:

```
String texto = txtNumero.getText();
num = Integer.parseInt(texto);
```

Ya el resto es lo mismo. ¡Espero haberte ayudado! ¡Saludos!